# How to remote onto networked PC using powershell

Tags: windows-7, powershell, scripting, remote-access

Is someone able to explain to me how I am able to connect onto a pc on the same network as my pc using powershell or a powershell script?

for example my local pc is 192.168.1.250 and the remote pc is 192.168.1.251

Both windows 7 pcs and on a home network.

Thanks,
Alex Hawkins

Comment: Can you be more specific?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're referring to opening a remote powershell prompt then you would use:

```
Enter-PSSession -ComputerName dc1
```

This assumes you have made all the necessary configuration settings to allow this on the remote system.

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849707.aspx

Comment: Does the same go for using an IP address rather than -ComputerName?

Comment: I do believe it should also work with the IP, but you still use the -ComputerName switch